# Two step click on mobile device hover

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 divs. The first div disappears on hover and the second div takes its  place. My second div contains a link inside. My problem is on mobile devices I can't see the content of the second div because when I click on the first div the hover effect on the link takes the lead.

```
<div class="boxInside">
   <div class="content">
       ... some content
   </div>
</div>
<div class="boxInsideHover">
   <a href="exemple.com">
      <div class="content">
          ... some content
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

What I want on mobile is one click to see the second div's content and another click after for the link.

Thank you

Comment: Highly recommend using [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events)

Comment: use clear:both; and overflow:auto;